# Erro ao executar o keras.models.Sequential() com tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, osx, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

Efetuei a importação do keras.models como especificado na documentação

Importação:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

Na hora da criação do model tento executar o Sequential me retorna um erro:

Execução:

```
 model = Sequential()
```

Log do erro:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcosmw/Documents/Meus_codigos/neural_network/classificacao_imagens/clk.py", line 90, in <module>
    model = Sequential()
  File "/Users/marcosmw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 87, in __init__
    super(Sequential, self).__init__(name=name)
  File "/Users/marcosmw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/marcosmw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 96, in __init__
    self._init_subclassed_network(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/marcosmw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 294, in _init_subclassed_network
    self._base_init(name=name)
  File "/Users/marcosmw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 109, in _base_init
    name = prefix + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
  File "/Users/marcosmw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 74, in get_uid
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

Sistema operacional: MacOS Catalina 10.15.1
Versão fo TensorFlow : 2.0.0
versão do keras: 2.2.4

Comment: Além do `Sequential` você também está importando o `Backend`?

Comment: Sim, já efetuei trocas de versão até do anaconda e continua com o erro

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o seu problema não é com o `Sequential`, mas com o `Backend`.

Subsitua o

```
from keras import backend
```

por

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend
```

Se você quiser ler a `issue` do GitHub clique [aqui](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12379) e depois [aqui](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12783)